# Flutter BackdropFilter for Appbar

Tags: flutter

how can i use `BackdropFilter` in flutter for `Appbar` ? when i use that for the `Appbar`other widgets which they are  into `Scaffold` blurred, not `AppBar`

for example:

```
BackdropFilter(
  filter: ImageFilter.blur(
      sigmaX: 5,
      sigmaY: 5
  ),

  child: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      // Used for removing back button.
      elevation: 8.0,
      titleSpacing: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: theme.appMainColor,
      title: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[

        ],
      )),
),
```

Comment: Have you found an answer to this problem? I am facing the same.

Comment: @j.unruh no i can't

Answer (score 9):

After searching web for a while and trying different combinations of widgets, I finally found the solution

```
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      child: Container(
        child: ClipRRect(
            child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                child: Container(
                  //   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  //  height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ))),
      ),
      preferredSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 22),
    ),
```

Go nuts!!

Comment: Instead of the inner Container you can also use the AppBar Widget. And / or save it in a separate variable to get the default AppBar height: `appBar.preferredSize.height;`

Comment: I found that I had to keep that Container widget and put the AppBar as a child. Although seemingly redundant, without that Container, the blur kept applying to the whole page.

Answer (score 9):

1. Use the [flexibleSpace](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/flexibleSpace.html) parameter of the `AppBar`.
2. Wrap the `BackDropFilter` with a `ClipRect` to prevent the blur from getting all over the screen.
3. Make sure to create a `Container` as the child of the `BackDropFilter`

Here is the minimal code you'll need to add to your `AppBar`:

```
flexibleSpace: ClipRect(
  child: BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 7, sigmaY: 7),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  ),
),
```